# How i can register the map reduce function in mongodb server and hit it from java

Tags: java, mongodb

```
db.PORTFOLIO_DATA_STRUCTURE_TEMP3.group({
    "key": {
        "target": true,
        "source": true,
        "expression": true
    },
    "initial": {
        "exp_count": 0,
        "sumforaveragevalue": 0,
        "countforaveragevalue": 0
    },
    "reduce": function(obj, prev) {
        if (obj.expression != null) if (obj.expression instanceof Array) prev.exp_count += obj.expression.length;
        else prev.exp_count++;
        prev.sumforaveragevalue += obj.score;
        prev.countforaveragevalue++;
    },
    "finalize": function(prev) {
        prev.value = prev.sumforaveragevalue / prev.countforaveragevalue;
        delete prev.sumforaveragevalue;
        delete prev.countforaveragevalue;
    }
});
```